# Variable Sizes Array in CUDA

Tags: cuda

Is there any way to declare an array such as:

```
int arraySize = 10;
int array[arraySize];
```

inside a CUDA kernel/function?  I read in another post that I could declare the size of the shared memory in the kernel call and then I would be able to do:

```
int array[];
```

But I cannot do this.  I get a compile error: "incomplete type is not allowed".  On a side note, I've also read that printf() can be called from within a thread and this also throws an error: "Cannot call host function from inside device/global function".

Is there anything I can do to make a variable sized array or equivalent inside CUDA? I am at compute capability 1.1, does this have anything to do with it?  Can I get around the variable size array declarations from within a thread by defining a `typedef struct` which has a size variable I can set?  Solutions for compute capabilities besides 1.1 are welcome.  This is for a class team project and if there is at least some way to do it I can at least present that information.

Answer (score 2):

About the printf, the problem is it only works for compute capability 2.x. There is an alternative cuPrintf that you might try.

For the allocation of variable size arrays in CUDA you do it like this:

- Inside the kernel you write `extern __shared__ int[];`
- On the kernel call you pass as the third launch parameter the shared memory size in bytes like `mykernel<<<gridsize, blocksize, sharedmemsize>>>();`

This is explained in the [CUDA C programming guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) in section B.2.3 about the `__shared__` qualifier.

Comment: What if each thread has to declare an array of a different variable size?  What if in addition each thread determines this size within its execution?

Comment: What you are talking about is possible using dynamic memory allocation inside each thread but it is really slow. And also only available on compute capability 2.x (section B.15 of the guide btw)

Comment: OK thanks.  I am not sure what I am going to do then.  The whole point of using the GPU is the project has to do with data mining research and the algorithm is too slow, so I am not sure what we are going to do to get around this.  An array is passed in and each thread constructs a different array based on the data in the parameter array so having it in shared will not work this way.  I guess instead of calling multiple threads inside one block I can call multiple blocks with one thread so the shared memory spaces don't clash!!

Comment: And that will be terribly slow also. You should always have a number of threads per block multiple of the warp size to maximize efficiency. You have to think and adapt your problem to the CUDA architecture, identify easily parallelizable parts. What you are trying to do might not even be suited for CUDA, not everything is. CUDA really shines when you want to do the same operation for each element on a big data set. It's the way of the SIMD architecture, single instruction, multiple data. If you tell more details in a different question about your problem maybe we can help.

Comment: It is a very parallel algorithm, just not really in the right combinations!  It seems like there is always one integer or variable that needs to be calculated before I can do something else.  We have two solutions and it looks like this one is just not going to produce the speedups were looking for.  It is a classifier algorithm.  It discretizes information, for example a plant's petal length, petal width, plant height, etc, with the intention to classify what type of plant it is.  The algorithm then starts removing thresholds one at a time between different features, like petal length,

Comment: and based on a set of training data, determines the best way to discretize the data to give the lowest probability of error when used on test data.  The idea was since removing each threshold can be done separately, do them in parallel, since there can be many thresholds and many features.  We thought up two approaches, the one that this post applies to is launching the kernel to remove a threshold, merge the data from the levels above and below that threshold, then calculate the probability of error, all in one kernel launch.  Looks like we will go with approach 2:

Comment: Do the merge alone in parallel, do the probability of error alone in parallel, etc, which leaves a top level for loop that I just can't unroll unless I can efficiently and dynamically allocate arrays without rewriting the merge, p of error, ... algorithms completely from scratch and its too late for that!!

Comment: The idea was a question, not 4 comments :P (they have a character limit for a reason). About your problem I don't know. Separating things is a good approach. If you already have a CPU implementation you can time it and see the parts that are slowest and where you would gain most by applying parallel processing. Searching for classifier algorithm GPU on google returns some paper results. Don't know if some of them applies to your problem. If the algorithm has a name you might have more luck searching. (SVM maybe?)

Answer (score 0):

If your arrays can be large, one solution would be to have one kernel that computes the required array sizes, stores them in an array, then after that invocation, the host allocates the necessary arrays and passes an array of pointers to the threads, and then you run your computation as a second kernel.

Whether this helps depends on what you have to do, because it would be arrays allocated in global memory. If the total size (per block) of your arrays is less than the size of the available shared memory, you could have a sufficiently-large shared memory array and let your threads negociate splitting it amongst themselves.

Comment: I had considered something along those lines, as well some other ideas, just am trying to avoid multiple kernel calls or anything that will slow this already slow algorithm down lol!!  I think that might end up being the best solution though thanks!!

Comment: In some cases 2 simple kernels will give better performance than 1 complex do-all-at-once kernel. Try exploit parallelism as much as you can. Divide and Conquer :)